# Какое посоветуете решение по хранению приватного видео контента для блога?

Tags: видео, youtube, google-drive, облако

Суть такая:
Пытаюсь найти решение (возможно облачное) для хранения и вопроспроизведения в авторском блоге видеоконтента, с доступом только для атворизированных пользователей блога.
Всего видео контента планируется залить на 2-4 террабайта.

Например есть облачный сервис vimeo. 
Но не могу разобраться, ок ли он. Какую апиху облачного сервиса можно взять, чтобы не резало качество и трафик, и было адекватно по цене? 
Прорабатывал еще вариант в приватный ютюб канал располагать имейлы, по которым регистрировались пользователи (но встал вопрос, а как тогда быть, если пользователь регистрировался в блог не на тот почтовый ящик, с которого залогинен в ютюб).

Так же прорабатывал вариант с гугл драйвом - купить место там и вставлять видео оттуда. Тогда видео будет просто открываться в окошке без возможности скопировать ссылку. Но встал вопрос, а можно ли будет настроить видео, чтобы окно было симпатичнее нежели стандартное воспроизведение через драйв?

В общем нужен ваш совет, каким сервисом и решением из вышеперечисленных (или любых других) лучше воспользоваться для данной цели.

Answer (score 0):

Наиболее разумным мне представляется решение использовать приватный YouTube канал. Отличное качество, многофункциональное API для управления видео из блога, встроенное управление доступом.

Проблемы с синхронизацией аккаунтов google и вашего блога не вижу. Есть такая штука [OneAll](http://oneall.com), она позволяет логиниться в блог через аккаунты в соцсетях. Имеет плагины для WordPress, Joomla, Drupal, phpBB, Magento, ну и тд и тп.